# How do I run Artisan Commands in ElasticBeanStalk

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, config

So, I created the `.ebextensions` folder and created a `queue_worker.config` file in the folder with the following content:

```
container_commands:
 queue_worker:
 command: "php artisan queue:work"
```

I got an error report `Could not open input file: artisan`. I even tried `"php /var/app/ondeck/artisan queue:work"` but still having the same error.

Please, how can I run artisan correctly without the EBS CLI tool?

Answer (score 0):

**/var/app/*** are owned by root. Please change your user to **root** in queue_worker.config then run your deployment again.